# Optgroup for dropdownlist in MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

In my MVC 4 application I was looking for optgroup for dropdownlist and found **[this](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2014/01/html5-dropdownlist-optgroup-tag-in-mvc.html)** very helpful.

I followed the steps and achieved that as well but currently I am facing some issues.My controller code looks like:

```
Model.ddlProject = db.Projects.OrderBy(t => t.Type)
                    .Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
                     {
                       GroupName = t.Type,
                       Text = t.Name,
                       Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)t.Id)
                      });
```

The grouping is done here but I want it in a different manner.With this I am able to bind the dropdown as shown below:

[image]

Now let me tell about my table structure.I have one table with following structure:

[image]

Here I have one hierarchy such that Customer -> Client -> Projects . Thus, I need to group by Clients such that all the projects should be listed under the clients.I want something like this:

[image]

Hence I have been stuck with query over here,the query to achieve this.I need to show all the client names in the group name and for clients I need to list all the respective projects.I guess I am clear with my requirement.Kind of got stuck here so any help would be great.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should consider restructuring your database tables. Projects and Clients are 2 different things. You should have a Client table and a separate Project table containing a column with foreign key to the Client table.

Comment: I was wondering about this scenario where I do need different tables but I am not supposed to change the database structure.So is  there any possible way of achieving this without the db change.Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Probably not. I cant see any way of grouping your data. You could create you own class to represent the hierarchical structure and loop through each row to assign the values but why bother. Just create you database correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As **Stephen Muecke** said in the comment section that Projects and Clients are 2 different things. You should have a Client table and a separate Project table containing a column with foreign key to the Client table. So below solution is according to your existing table structure.

**Dummy Schema**

```
DECLARE @clientprj TABLE ([id] int identity(1,1), [name] varchar(30), Desc1 varchar(30), ParentId int, pType varchar(30));

INSERT @clientprj ([name], Desc1, ParentId, pType) VALUES ('client1', '', 0, 'clt'), ('prj1', '', 1, 'prj'), ('prj2', '', 1, 'prj'), ('client2', '', 0, 'clt'), ('prj n', '', 4, 'prj')
```

and Here is the query

```
SELECT GroupName, GroupKey, ProjName, ProjId
FROM 
(
    (
        SELECT NAME AS GroupName
            ,Id AS GroupKey
        FROM @clientprj m
        WHERE ParentId = 0
        ) m 
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT NAME AS ProjName
            ,Id AS ProjId
            ,ParentId
        FROM @clientprj
    ) 
    t ON m.GroupKey = t.ParentId
)
WHERE ParentId <> 0
```

Which return the following output.

```
GroupName   GroupKey    ProjName    ProjId
client1       1           prj1           2
client1       1           prj2           3
client2       4           prj n          5
```

and your controller method which calls this query like this -

```
Model.ddlProject = db.NewMethod
                    .Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
                     {
                       GroupName = t.GroupName,
                       GroupKey = t.GroupKey.ToString(),
                       Text = t.ProjName,
                       Value = t.ProjId.ToString()
                      });
```

and then bind your dropdownlist. Best of luck...